# GCP Increase quota `Domain registrations` within Cloud Domains API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

I am currently trying to figure out why I can not increase my quota for Domain registrations within Cloud Domains API ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCv5Q.png)).

My GCP project is a private/personal one, but yet, it is **not free tier** (it started off as a free tier project but then I upgraded it).
As stated within the screenshot there is also the option to contact sales...so is this the only way?
I've also looked into the separate service https://domains.google/ for renting domains. However I would love to see my GCP bill + Domain bill on the same billing account.
Speaking of the billing account: It is all "green" so I don't think the issue lies here.

Happy on your thoughts!

What I have done so far is request a general quota increase: `Google Cloud Platform/API Project: Request Project Quota Increase`. Which was granted (2 days ago).
However I afterwards I still can not increase the quota for domain registrations.

Within IAM I have the `domains.registrations.create` Role (I am the GCP projects owner anyway and the only one working on it).

Comment: This is not an answer, but an informed comment. Google has sold Google Domains to Squarespace. I am not sure if that is related to your issue, but Google might not be allocating domain resources to new customers. That is purely a guess on my part. https://support.google.com/domains/answer/13689670?hl=en In any event, we cannot help you with a quota issue. You must contact Google support. Only they can adjust or correct quotas.